# Magento stopped generating sitemap suddenly

Tags: magento, sitemap, fishpig

Sitemap stopped generating suddenly.
Started displaying '**Unable to create XML sitemap.**'
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix to it .
Here I am using fishpig extension .
Observed that fishpig is overridding magento core sitemap controller .
So added the following code : `/app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/controllers/Adminhtml/SitemapController.php`

Add this code before :

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sitemap_id');
        $sitemap = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap');
        /* @var $sitemap Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap */
        $sitemap->load($id);
        // if sitemap record exists
        if ($sitemap->getId()) {
            try {
                $sitemap->generateXml();

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('The sitemap "%s" has been generated.', $sitemap->getSitemapFilename()));
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
                    Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Unable to generate the sitemap.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(
                Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Unable to find a sitemap to generate.'));
        }
```

Hope it helps someone experiencing with same issue .

*Courtesy : lukecollymore*